# Kubernetes: Pull images from internal registry with on-premise deployment

Tags: docker, kubernetes

**tl;dr** How do you reference an image in a Kubernetes `Pod` when the image is from a private docker registry hosted on the same k8s cluster without a separate DNS entry for the registry?

In an on-premise Kubernetes deployment, I have setup a private Docker registry using the [stable/docker-registry](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/docker-registry) helm chart using a self-signed certificate. This is on-premise and I can't setup a DNS record to give the registry it's own URL. I wish to use these manifests as templates, so I don't want to hardcode any environment specific config.

The docker registry service is of type `ClusterIP` and looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: docker-registry
  labels:
    app: docker-registry
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      name: registry
      targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: docker-registry
```

If I've pushed an image to this registry manually (or in the future via a Jenkins build pipeline), how would I reference that image in a `Pod` spec?

I have tried:

```
containers:
- name: my-image
  image: docker-registry.devops.svc.cluster.local/my-image:latest
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

But I received an error about the node host not being able to resolve `docker-registry.devops.svc.cluster.local`. I think the Docker daemon on the k8s node can't resolve that URL because it is an internal k8s DNS record.

```
Warning  Failed     20s (x2 over 34s)  kubelet, ciabdev01-node3  
Failed to pull image "docker-registry.devops.svc.cluster.local/hadoop-datanode:2.7.3": 
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://docker-registry.devops.svc.cluster.local/v2/: dial tcp: lookup docker-registry.devops.svc.cluster.local: no such host
Warning  Failed     20s (x2 over 34s)  kubelet, node3  Error: ErrImagePull
```

So, how would I reference an image on an internally hosted docker registry in this on-premise scenario?

Is my only option to use a service of type `NodePort`, reference one of the node's hostname in the `Pod` spec, and then configure each node's docker daemon to ignore the self signed certificate?

Comment: i think the problem is not that it cannot resolve the name but that it does not trust it. docker normally skips security only if regestry name is localhost. i do use this on minikube since there is only one node but otherwise it would not work.

Comment: @PavelAgarkov The self signed certificate will indeed become a problem, but the error I shared definitely says it cannot find the host. When I change the service to NodePort, I can reference the image by using the host name of the master node, but then the error becomes about the self-signed certificate. I guess I'll have to distribute the certificate to each node in the cluster.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Docker uses DNS settings configured on the Node, and, by default, it does not see DNS names declared in the Kubernetes cluster.

You can try to use one of the following solutions:

1. Use the IP address from `ClusterIP` field in "docker-registry" Service description as docker registry name. This address is static until you recreate the service. Also, you can add this IP address to `/etc/hosts` on each node.

   For example, you can add `my-docker-registry 10.11.12.13` line to `/etc/hosts` file. Therefore, you can use `10.11.12.13:5000` or `my-docker-registry:5000` as docker registry name for `image` field in Pods description.
2. Expose "docker-registry" Service outside the cluster using `type: NodePort`. Than use `localhost:<exposed_port>` or `<one_of_nodes_name>:<exposed_port>` as docker registry name for `image` field in Pods description.

Comment: I was hoping for an elegant solution that aboids having to bootstrap a new node, so #2 seems like the best way forward. I can define the `nodePort` in my registry manifest, and then set image to `localhost:<nodePort>`  in all other manifests.

Comment: Hi @Artem, both the approaches works great. 
However, is there a way to use secret as described in k8s docs below with private registries hosted within same cluster?

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod